# How to pass index to child function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the question. I want to pass index of each child element to the function **handleChange**, but I can't get it))) When I click on TabPanelItem appears error **handleChange is not a function**
What's the problem?

Parent Element:

```
const TabPanel = () => {

    const tabsPanelData = [
        {label: 'tab1'},
        {label: 'tab2'},
        {label: 'tab3'}
    ];

    const [tabIndex, settabIndex] = useState(0);

    const handleChange = (index) => {
        console.log(index);
    }


    return (
        <StyledTabPanel>
            
            {tabsPanelData.map((tabPanelItem, i) => {
                const {label, handleChange} = tabPanelItem;
                return (
                    <TabPanelItem
                    key={i}
                    label={label}
                    handleChange={handleChange(i)}
                  />
                )
            })}
        </StyledTabPanel>
    )
}
```

and my child component:

```
const TabPanelItem = ({ label, handleChange }) => {


    return (
      <StyledTabPanelItem
      
      onClick={handleChange}>
         {label}
      </StyledTabPanelItem>
    )
}
```

Comment: `handleChange={handleChange(i)}` will call the function immediately when rendered. Consider passing a function instead of a function call? `handleChange={() => handleChange(i)}`

Comment: @evolutionxbox yeah thanks, but the problem is still here))

Comment: What problem? You haven't actually said what the issue is.

Comment: @evolutionxbox maybe im not passing props right?)

Comment: Ah, you seem to have a duplicate `handleChange`. Please try using `const { label } = tabPanelItem;` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you made a mistake in this line

```
const {label, handleChange} = tabPanelItem;
```

you dont handleChange in the tablePanelItem

it should be

```
const {label} = tabPanelItem;
```

and you are executing the function `handleChange` by doing this

```
  <TabPanelItem
       key={i}
       label={label}
       handleChange={handleChange(i)}
/>
```

you either pass the `handleChange` function as the body of an arrow function as the props of the `TabPanelItem`

```
<TabPanelItem
   key={i}
   label={label}
   handleChange={() => handleChange(i)}
/>
```

then on click that arrow function would be executed

Comment: sorry you need that line .. you just made a mistake , handleChange is not part of the tabPanelItem .. so you are initializing the handleChange variable , so it would not point to the function you made outside that scope